Connection to ActiveMQ Artemis from Java application using spring-boot-starter-artemis fails
My Java application uses Spring Boot and connects to ActiveMQ Artemis. It works good with local ActiveMQ Artemis version 2.9, but the connection fails with cloud ActiveMQ Artemis 2.17. However, I can see remote console and do all actions - browse, send, etc. So, remote ActiveMQ Artemis is accessible.
From the log file I see that initially application connected and failed with exception
org.apache.activemq.artemis.api.core.ActiveMQNotConnectedException: AMQ219006: Channel disconnected

Here is part of log:
DEBUG [main] Connector NettyConnector [host=********, port=61617, httpEnabled=false, httpUpgradeEnabled=false, useServlet=false, servletPath=/messaging/ActiveMQServlet, sslEnabled=false, useNio=true] using nio
DEBUG [main] Started NIO Netty Connector version 4.1.104.Final to ********:61617
DEBUG [main] Remote destination: ********:61617
DEBUG [main] -Dio.netty.processId: 33688 (auto-detected)
DEBUG [main] -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack: false
DEBUG [main] -Djava.net.preferIPv6Addresses: false
DEBUG [main] Loopback interface: lo (Software Loopback Interface 1, 127.0.0.1)
DEBUG [main] Failed to get SOMAXCONN from sysctl and file \proc\sys\net\core\somaxconn. Default: 200
DEBUG [main] -Dio.netty.machineId: 00:05:9a:ff:fe:3c:7a:00 (auto-detected)
DEBUG [main] -Dio.netty.allocator.numHeapArenas: 32
DEBUG [main] -Dio.netty.allocator.numDirectArenas: 32
DEBUG [main] -Dio.netty.allocator.pageSize: 8192
DEBUG [main] -Dio.netty.allocator.maxOrder: 9
DEBUG [main] -Dio.netty.allocator.chunkSize: 4194304
DEBUG [main] -Dio.netty.allocator.smallCacheSize: 256
DEBUG [main] -Dio.netty.allocator.normalCacheSize: 64
DEBUG [main] -Dio.netty.allocator.maxCachedBufferCapacity: 32768
DEBUG [main] -Dio.netty.allocator.cacheTrimInterval: 8192
DEBUG [main] -Dio.netty.allocator.cacheTrimIntervalMillis: 0
DEBUG [main] -Dio.netty.allocator.useCacheForAllThreads: false
DEBUG [main] -Dio.netty.allocator.maxCachedByteBuffersPerChunk: 1023
DEBUG [main] -Dio.netty.allocator.type: pooled
DEBUG [main] -Dio.netty.threadLocalDirectBufferSize: 0
DEBUG [main] -Dio.netty.maxThreadLocalCharBufferSize: 16384
DEBUG [main] -Dio.netty.bootstrap.extensions: null
DEBUG [Thread-0 (ActiveMQ-client-netty-threads)] Added ActiveMQClientChannelHandler to Channel with id = 73c752b3 
DEBUG [main] Connected with the currentConnectorConfig=TransportConfiguration(name=null, factory=org-apache-activemq-artemis-core-remoting-impl-netty-NettyConnectorFactory) ?port=61617&host=********
DEBUG [main] -Dio.netty.buffer.checkAccessible: true
DEBUG [main] -Dio.netty.buffer.checkBounds: true
DEBUG [main] Loaded default ResourceLeakDetector: io.netty.util.ResourceLeakDetector@5f61e002
DEBUG [main] -Dio.netty.recycler.maxCapacityPerThread: 4096
DEBUG [main] -Dio.netty.recycler.ratio: 8
DEBUG [main] -Dio.netty.recycler.chunkSize: 32
DEBUG [main] -Dio.netty.recycler.blocking: false
DEBUG [main] -Dio.netty.recycler.batchFastThreadLocalOnly: true
DEBUG [main] Reconnection successful
DEBUG [main] ClientSessionFactoryImpl received backup update for live/backup pair = TransportConfiguration(name=null, factory=org-apache-activemq-artemis-core-remoting-impl-netty-NettyConnectorFactory) ?port=61617&host=******** / null  but it didn't belong to TransportConfiguration(name=null, factory=org-apache-activemq-artemis-core-remoting-impl-netty-NettyConnectorFactory) ?port=61617&host=********
DEBUG [Thread-0 (ActiveMQ-client-global-threads)] Failure captured on connectionID=73c752b3, performing failover or reconnection now
org.apache.activemq.artemis.api.core.ActiveMQNotConnectedException: AMQ219006: Channel disconnected
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client.impl.ClientSessionFactoryImpl.connectionDestroyed(ClientSessionFactoryImpl.java:410)
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.remoting.impl.netty.NettyConnector$Listener$1.run(NettyConnector.java:1240)
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.utils.actors.OrderedExecutor.doTask(OrderedExecutor.java:57)
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.utils.actors.OrderedExecutor.doTask(OrderedExecutor.java:32)
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.utils.actors.ProcessorBase.executePendingTasks(ProcessorBase.java:68)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.utils.ActiveMQThreadFactory$1.run(ActiveMQThreadFactory.java:118)

pom.xml:
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd"><modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.1</version><relativePath/>
    </parent>

    <groupId>***</groupId>
    <artifactId>***</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <name>***</name>
    <description>***</description>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.target>17</maven.compiler.target>
        <maven.compiler.source>17</maven.compiler.source>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>  
    </properties>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>                                       
            </plugin>                   
        </plugins>
    </build>
    
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>    
        </dependency>        
              <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-artemis</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-integration-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

I tried another ActiveMQ Artemis cloud installation and got the same result. I created separate project just for this problem.

Your client is attempting to connect to port 61617, but that is not the default port so it's possible the remote broker(s) are not listening on that port. Have you tried connecting to 61616 (i.e. the default port)?

Hi Justin, port 61617 is right, I can check it from Artemis Console and in broker.xml. And I also tested it. Doesn't help.

Is there anything worth noting in the broker logs? This seems like some sort of environmental issue since it works locally but not remotely. If you can provide me with a way to reproduce what you're observing then I can investigate further.

Have you tried connecting to a Docker instance of ActiveMQ Artemis?

Hi Frank, I don't use Docker instance because this is customer environment, not my.

Hi @Justin Bertram,  now I guess (after all other versions) maybe problem is in broker.xml acceptor
tcp://:61617?sslEnabled=true;needClientAuth=true;keyStorePath=/apps/os/config/mykeys/.jks;keyStorePassword=123456;trustStorePath=/apps/os/config/mykeys/**.truststore.jks;trustStorePassword=123456;tcpSendBufferSize=1048576;tcpReceiveBufferSize=1048576;protocols=CORE,AMQP,STOMP,HORNETQ,MQTT,OPENWIRE;useEpoll=true;amqpCredits=1000;amqpLowCredits=300
Because it suppose to get only secured messages.

@JustinBertram - if I put in broker.xml acceptor for 0.0.0.0, it works, I mean JmsListener is waiting for messages. Fine. But I need to use cluster configuration for 3 nodes, I cannot put acceptor 0.0.0.0. If I put real URI, I get the same exception.
tcp://0.0.0.0:61617?tcpSendBufferSize=1048576;tcpReceiveBufferSize=1048576;protocols=CORE,AMQP,STOMP,HORNETQ,MQTT,OPENWIRE;useEpoll=true;amqpCredits=1000;amqpLowCredits=300
Do you have any ideas?
